# Why is flexbox making my ad content disappear (sometimes)?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using flexbox to center div containers that contain google ads on mobile devices. I have 2 containers that can be described as such...

```
<div class='outer'>
   <div id='ad-container'></div>
</div>
```

the outer class has the following CSS properties

```
align-items: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
padding: 70px 0px;
min-height: 84vw;
```

Normally, this works fine, and the ad the gets filled in the `ad-container` id is centered fine as such...

[image: image with flexbox working fine]

Sometimes however, I'll get a scenario where there is no image there and instead the vertical space grows and has 0px width, again shown below.

[image: image with flexbox not working fine]

In such a scenario I notice that if I go into the chrome dev tools and manually click off `display: flex;` the ad will then appear like normal, implying that for some reason, flexbox just completely mushes it.

[image: image that didn't work with flexbox. I then click off display: flex;, and it shows up]

The pattern I've seemed to notice is that this may have to do with ads on mobile devices that want to conform to 100% of the device screen width. But I don't know why that would be and if there's any middle ground in CSS I can do to prevent this while still using flexbox.

Does anybody have any idea as to if flexbox has any limitations for things like this?

EDIT: I also know that it is possible the answer here is just sometimes ads are dumb and there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the limitation of the flexbox. That is how the flexbox suppose to work. By default the flex items within the flexbox can grow and shrink. To avoid the shrinking of an item you can try **flex-shrink: 0;**